# Grails Hibernate persistent set: how to not save automatically

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class Teacher that has many Students.

When I use

```
Teacher.students.each{it->
      it.lastupdated=date;
}
```

The property for the student is persisted to the database automatically (and seemingly immediately).

Is there a way to prevent this behavior and have the values be transient until I explicitly save them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply with `it.discard()` to avoid the auto-save. Check the Grails documentation [here](http://docs.grails.org/2.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/discard.html).

Another solution, which may not work for your Grails version, is to add this on your configuration file:

```
hibernate {
    flush.mode='manual'
}
```

Comment: then using save() manually will persist the new values? Or will it still discard those?

Comment: According to the Grails documentation, `discard()` only removes the autosave. If you manually call `save()`, then your modifications will be applied.